# Alibaba Cloud Terraform Apply - ErrorCode: RISK.RISK_CONTROL_REJECTION & ErrorCode: Forbidden.RiskControl

Tags: terraform, alibaba-cloud

I want to create 2 instance (an instance Zone A, and an instance Zone B), Private IP, SLB (Public IP), the VServer is both instance (for SLB), Frontend and Backend Port are HTTP. Regarding my terraform scripts are [here](https://github.com/gablooge/alibaba-terraform-challenge): https://github.com/gablooge/alibaba-terraform-challenge

But I have a problem when applying my scripts. It turned out like this when creating the instance and SLB on applying my terraform scripts. Here are the error messages:

> Error: [ERROR] terraform-provider-alicloud/alicloud/resource_alicloud_instance.go:423: Resource alicloud_instance RunInstances Failed!!! [SDK alibaba-cloud-sdk-go ERROR]:
> SDK.ServerError
> ErrorCode: Forbidden.RiskControl
> Recommend:
> RequestId: 09B3E699-BC3E-457B-B266-54AC66325BE7
> Message: This operation is forbidden by Aliyun RiskControl system.
>
> on main.tf line 1, in resource "alicloud_instance" "instance_a":
> 1: resource "alicloud_instance" "instance_a" {
>
> Error: [ERROR] terraform-provider-alicloud/alicloud/resource_alicloud_instance.go:423: Resource alicloud_instance RunInstances Failed!!! [SDK alibaba-cloud-sdk-go ERROR]:
> SDK.ServerError
> ErrorCode: Forbidden.RiskControl
> Recommend:
> RequestId: 5520BCA6-6A03-4E3A-A87E-1794AC38AB11
> Message: This operation is forbidden by Aliyun RiskControl system.
>
> on main.tf line 15, in resource "alicloud_instance" "instance_b":
> 15: resource "alicloud_instance" "instance_b" {
>
> Error: [ERROR] terraform-provider-alicloud/alicloud/resource_alicloud_slb.go:244: Resource alicloud_slb CreateLoadBalancer Failed!!! [SDK alibaba-cloud-sdk-go ERROR]:
> SDK.ServerError
> ErrorCode: RISK.RISK_CONTROL_REJECTION
> Recommend:
> RequestId: D677A5EB-F3A7-48A2-98D1-91988BAF6B53
> Message: The Account is rejected by risk control system.
>
> on main.tf line 30, in resource "alicloud_slb" "default":
> 30: resource "alicloud_slb" "default" {

[Alibaba Cloud Terraform Apply - ErrorCode: RISK.RISK_CONTROL_REJECTION & ErrorCode: Forbidden.RiskControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpvSi.jpg)

Anybody know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Is your account a RAM user? If so, check the permissions. Perhaps try creating the resources through console first to make sure.

Comment: Yes, I have configured the access for the ram user that I have used for terraform..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like access related issue. You might want to check with raise a ticket with Alibaba Cloud support team to confirm all the required access is enabled.